# Can I use autowiring for a private method within a controller class?

Tags: php, symfony

In Symfony 5.4, there's the very nimble autowiring that enables to easily access to custom repository methods inside a controller:

```php
private function getPageContent(PageVisiteurRepository $pageVisiteur)
{ /* ... */ }
```

But now in the `getPageContent()` method, how can I add the parameter `$pageSource`? When I call the function, it asks for two parameters now, and counts the dependency injection as a parameter:

```php
private function getPageContent(PageVisiteurRepository $pageVisiteur, $pageSource)
{ /* ... */ }

public function appPage(): Response
{
   $pageContent = $this->getPageContent('My Page Source');
   // ... 
}
```

Doesn't work.

I stumble on this problem now and then on various cases that call to create a custom class in a controller that needs at the same time to call the repository class and to have parameters.

What's the proper way to deal with this question in recent Symfony versions?

To give some context, here I have an app where I want to include specific page content that is stored in the database as an addendum to the already existing application page, using a custom request stored in my `PageVisiteurRepository`.

Comment: Have you tried DI from the constructor instead of the method?
Move repository up to the constructor and remove the DI from the method. In that case you can then call the method without the repository.

Comment: Anytime you call a method directly it is up to you to pass all the necessary arguments.  You might be getting confused by Symfony's ability to call controller action methods (appPage in your code) and resolve the arguments.  There is actually an entire sub-system that implements this functionality.  It is not part of the service container or the autowire capability.  It's only possible to do this because Symfony itself is the only one who calls these particular methods.

Comment: I've made some corrections, thanks for the comments all ! Please keep in mind that I kept the code to the bare minimum for readability. @yivi : the private method is to make some custom operations : calls to a custom repository method and other modifications, that will apply on several controller methods. Why the downvote ? I took some time to gather that question that I feel is of interest especially for people like me that still struggle to put together the Symfony bricks, if it isn't I'll delete that post.

Comment: Bit off-topic perhaps but when you find yourself writing methods used by multiple controller actions then you should consider moving those methods into their own services.  In general you want to minimize the amount of business logic that is implemented in controllers.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use autowiring from private methods.

Autowiring the controller methods directly is a special case of autowiring, and works only for controller methods (e.g. methods that handle a "route").
But generally, for autowiring you'd use the constructor:

```
class Whatever {
   public  function __construct(private PageVisiteurRepository $repository) {}

   private function foo(string $title) {
      $something = $this->repository->getSomethingFromTheRepo($title);

      // do something with $something

      return $foo;
   }

   public function pageController($pageSource): Response {

      return new Response($this->foo($pageSource));

   }

}
```

You *could* do the same injecting the repo directly in the controller method:

```
class Whatever {
   private function foo(string $title, PageVisiteurRepository $repository) {
      $something = $repository->getSomethingFromTheRepo($title);

      // do something with $something

      return $foo;
   }

   public function pageController($pageSource, PageVisiteurRepository $repository): Response {

      return new Response($this->foo($pageSource, $repository));

   }

}
```